# How to display/use a dropdown in the django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

This is my first thing to build with Django! I have two models Products & Categories. I'm managing both in the admin section. I can create products, and I can create categories. How can I get a drop of the categories to show up on the page which creates a product. The product table already has a foreign key pointing to the categories table.

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
       return self.name

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)

    def __str__(self):
       return self.name


class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
         (None,      {'fields': ['name']}),
    ]

 admin.site.register(Category, CategoryAdmin)


 class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     fieldsets = [
        (None,          {'fields': ['name']}),
        (None,          {'fields': ['description']}),
     ]


 admin.site.register(Product, ProductAdmin)
```

Comment: The admin interface should do that automatically. How is the foreign key defined?

Comment: This seems right. Did you do something strange when you defined the Admin of each model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `category` field is missing because you have defined fieldsets for your model admin, but missing the category` field out. Change it to something like the following.

```
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     fieldsets = [
        (None,          {'fields': ['name']}),
        (None,          {'fields': ['description']}),
        (None,          {'fields': ['category']}),
    ]
```

As it's a foreign key, if should be a drop down select box by default.